# What are all the possible optimizations I could apply to a new build of Gentoo?

Tags: performance, cpu, gentoo, optimization

With the assumption that I'm using hardware with a very modern CPU (9900K), what are all the possible optimizations I could apply to a new build of Gentoo in order to gain the best possible performance and efficiency?

I plan to use the system as a typical desktop for playing games, web, watching films, work. I think the optimizations necessary for such varied tasks would be inherently general, so is there like a commonly used set, in the way that the Clear Linux distribution is made with a specific set of optimizations to increase speed over other distributions?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Please edit your question and tell us what you're going to use the system for.

Comment: I've made it as specific as I can

Answer (score 1):

To really get the best performance way more info about your system is needed and this also differs for each program.

Example: If you don't have much memory and the software is large, you'll need to optimize for size and not for cpu-speed.

To do everything correctly you will have to search what the bottleneck is in your case. And you will have to search this for each program. In many cases the bottleneck will be in different places.

In general, **but certainly not all the time**, the answer would be to compile with `-Ofast`.

Don't forget to take into account that you, as 1 person, are trying to optimize compilation of a large amount of software that is not written by you.
Unless you have really divergent hardware the standards set by the original programmers will be **extremely** hard to beat.

By manually tuning this you will, in most cases, even end up with slower software.